# awk output when run in background

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Im wondering why awk print different output when run in background

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Name of shell is $SHELL"
relase=`uname -r`
echo "Release is: $relase"
if [ $SHELL != "/bin/bash" ] || [ $relase != "3.13.0-32-generic" ] ; then
  echo "Warning, different configuration"
fi
if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo "Insert name of shell"
  read sname
else
   sname=$1
fi
awk -v sname="$sname" 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {if ($7 == sname) print $1 }' </etc/passwd &
```

When i run awk without ampersand, output is:

```
petr@PetrLinux-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ ./script1 /bin/bash
Name of shell is /bin/bash
Release is: 3.13.0-32-generic
root
petr
```

but when i run awk with ampersand - in background, output is folowing:

```
petr@PetrLinux-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ ./script1 /bin/bash
Name of shell is /bin/bash
Release is: 3.13.0-32-generic
petr@PetrLinux-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ root
petr
```

First record (root) is not printed on single line. Please tell me why ańd if there is way how to print on single line while running on background. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is a mix of two outputs. The first output is of your shell, printing the command prompt (`petr@PetrLinux-VirtualBox:~/Documents$`). The second output is `root` from your script.

As your shell script runs in the background, you now have two processes writing to your terminal window: the bash (printing the prompt), and your script, printing the awk-output. This then just mixes up.

The only way to prevent that is to redirect the output of the script to a file or other device, instead of your console. For example:
`$ ./script1 /bin/bash &> output.txt &`

Comment: You beat me by 37 seconds ;-)

Comment: Ah, another way of preventing this special problem or garbled output might be this little hack:  `(sleep 1; echo; ./script1 /bin/bash) &`  But of course, this is just a hack.

Comment: but that hack only works if the script runs for less than one second, doesn't it? In the actual case (parsing `/etc/passwd`), this might be the case. But then I wonder why running it in the background in the first place :-) But yes, it would also solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The output is the same.  It just appears to be different because two processes write on the same channel (your terminal) and mix their output.  One process is the awk script and the other is your shell which prints a new prompt.

There is no way to determine the precise point in which the output will switch from one process to the other.  It can be different on different systems (with the same software), it can also depend on the load of the computer and lots of other things.

The only decent solution is to redirect the output into a different stream, e. g. a file using `> outfile`.